# Loading in a php page with AJAX using Smarty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I'm looking to load my site pages using AJAX, therefore saving on loading the header and footer every time and just  changing the content.

How would I go about doing this as I am using smarty?

I'm aware that this may be the order it needs to go in:

--

Request PHP

parse TPL

make html

show in browser

--

I'm just not sure how to actually go about doing the second and third steps particularly.

Comment: Is there a reason you need AJAX?

Comment: Doing so, you will loose good SEO features.

Comment: That's not true @DainisAbols : You can do several things, for instance serve the content trough a hasbang and a 'normal' url, both ajax/complete.

Comment: True, but then again, that will not make the site much faster, only messier. Caching the footer and header will make the site faster + the site will work even if I turn of JavaScript.

Comment: The hashbang/direct url method will work for you if you turn of javascript, so that's not an issue. Apart from that, you must account for the speed "feel" -> if the page doesn't do a complete reload it can (I say can because you need to implement it right) feel quicker with the AJAX route. In the end, sure you can discuss if this is the best method, but it _could be_ the best, so that's enough for this question to be valid and not be discarded for "there is a better way, don't do this" reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Do what you would normally do.

For AJAX: Call some javascript function, retrieve to-show data, show data in some DOM location

For php/smarty: recieve request (from ajax, but who cares), do PHP stuff, fill smarty vars, call smarty show, return to-show data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways :

Call a jquery ajax function that change contents of div.

second :

Use iframe where you want change content.